# Permission denied when manually installing R package

Tags: r, linux, installation, package, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Hi I am currently run R code with version 4.1.0 on ubuntu(WSL) right now. I try to install some R packages manually because my internet is too slow, but I cannot get permission, the warning messages suggest the probable reason "permission denied". Here is the error and warning messages.

```r
Warning in dir.create(path, showWarnings = TRUE, recursive = TRUE, ...) :
  cannot create dir 'Rhdf5lib_1.14.2/Rhdf5lib', reason 'Permission denied'
Error in mydir.create(name) :
  failed to create directory ‘Rhdf5lib_1.14.2/Rhdf5lib’
```

I really hope someone can help me with this problem, thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you edit the question and also provide your path name? (Of course, with your name, company info etc. anonymized) Sometimes, the problem is that you are working with a folder that doesn't have writing rights.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start your R session with `sudo R`. Other possible option is to specify a lib argument like `install.packages("SomePackage", lib = "/home/user/R/...")`

Answer (score 0):

I try the following command

```r
export PATH=$PATH: path/to/your/R
```

and run R directly,this works for me.